# Azure Blob storage with directory mapping

Tags: azure, static, azure-blob-storage

I have two angular apps (lets say app1 and app2) hosted in two azure static web site enabled blob storage. and currently app1 is mapped to a custom domain ( lets say http://example.com). Now i have a requirement such that when user access the url http://example.com/app2, user should be redirected to app2 app without url is not changed in the browser.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have an account of Azure Storage general purpose v2 as the figure below.

[image]

And I configured my `Static website` tab as the figure below.

[image]

Continously, I directly uploaded a file named `index.html` to container `$web` as the `app1`'s index document, and uploaded a directory named `app2` which includes another `index.html` file as the `app2`'s index document, as the figure below.

[image]

Then, I got the index pages of `app1` and `app2` via the urls `https://<my storage account name>.z7.web.core.windows.net/` and `https://<my storage account name>.z7.web.core.windows.net/app2`

[image]

Finally, if you want to use a custom domain name, you just need to add a CNAME record in your DNS to combine `example.com` with `<my storage account name>.z7.web.core.windows.net`.